# How can I invoke a method on an instance using MSIL *without* having a MethodInfo?

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic-programming, cil

I have a number properties on a class that follow a particular convention. Eg.

```
Person1 { get; set; }
Person2 { get; set; }
Person3 { get; set; }
```

I don't want to have to get a `MethodInfo` object on the instance of the class, but do something like this instead:

```
...
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, [instance]["set_Person" + index]);
```

The above line of code is illustrative and not what I think it should be.

Does anyone know how I can get around to do this?

Comment: Use the DynamicMethod class.  There's good documentation on how to use it in the MSDN Library article for it.

Comment: Where does the index come from? Is it that parameter of the method you're creating? Or should it be constant in that one method?

Comment: @svick: The "index" comes from a for-loop within the creator of the DynamicMethod.

Comment: So why don't you want to get the `MethodInfo`? That won't have any impact on the performance of the generated code.

Comment: @svick But, i know it would be a powerful tool if i can do it without the MethodInfo.

Comment: What do you mean, “powerful tool”? In what way would it be better than using `MethodInfo`?

Comment: I believe it would provide a notch-up in performance.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. There is no `MethodInfo` at runtime in this case.

Comment: @svick Wouldn't be nice to still know how to do it? I would love to know.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done and I don't understand the point or any potential benefit. The MSIL Callvirt instruction does not take a string describing what to call, it takes a metadata token which points to a specific method on a specific type,  and the only way to get that value via reflection is with a MethodInfo instance.

This really doesn't seem like a complicated alternative:

```
il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, type.GetMethod("set_Person" + index));
```

Comment: The reason i asked the question was for performance reasons. If i don't have to use reflection a 1000 times, i'm sure i'll gain some speed. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: 1000 times would be completely unnoticeable to a user. If you are emitting IL you should be caching the resulting methods or classes and reusing them instead of emitting IL every single time you call a method, so the performance benefit would be nil. Also, if you are emitting IL, you will usually be calling methods that don't exist in statically linked code, i.e. dynamically discovered methods or other IL emitted methods, which you can pass in as MethodInfo objects.

Comment: That said, if you search for it there have been lots of requests for similar constructs to `typeof(SomeClass)` such as: `methodof(SomeClass.SomeMethod)`, `fieldof(SomeClass._someField)`, `propertyof(SomeClass.SomeProperty)`, etc...but I wouldn't hold your breath for it, the CLR team doesn't see those as high priority items.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Sample
{
    public int Person1 { get; set; }
    public int Person2 { get; set; }
    public int Person3 { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    var s = new  Sample();
    var tuples = new List<Tuple<string, int>> { 
                    Tuple.Create("Person1", 1), 
                    Tuple.Create("Person2", 2), 
                    Tuple.Create("Person3", 3) 
                 };

    var argument = Expression.Constant(s);

    foreach (var item in tuples) {
        CreateLambda(item.Item1, argument, item.Item2)
               .Compile()
               .DynamicInvoke();
    }
 }

static LambdaExpression CreateLambda(string propertyName, Expression instance, int value) {
     return Expression.Lambda(
               Expression.Assign(
                  Expression.PropertyOrField(instance, propertyName), 
                  Expression.Constant(value)));
 }
```

Comment: This looks nice, but not exactly what i was looking for. :) Let me try it and out.